# xticks are not getting displayed matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I have a block of code to plot 2 columns vs 1 column as a Line graph.

The Year, Month values (xticks) are not getting displayed in my plot for this simple block of code. Where am I going wrong?

Also, I get the same result with or without `plt.subplots`? Need an explanation on this, please.

```
plt.subplots(1, sharex=True)
df.col1.groupby([df["timestamp"].dt.year,df["timestamp"].dt.month]).mean()
            .plot('line')
df.col2.groupby([df["timestamp"].dt.year,df["timestamp"].dt.month]).mean()
            .plot('line').set_ylim(0, )
plt.title('Title')
plt.ylabel('ylabel')
plt.xlabel('(Year, Month)')
plt.legend(('col1', 'col2'))
plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
```

Comment: Please add more to make code reproducable

Comment: I am not sure what else you need from this.. This plot has to automatically take the xticks and yticks from the code.

Comment: Can you use a dataframe that I can also use, or create an example case that I can replicate.  Another option is to post a picture of the result